# jasmine beforeAll affected by sibling describe

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I was under the impression that the `beforeAll`-function would run once for the describe it was inside. However it seems that sibling describes can affect the `beforeAll`.

the following tests can be found [here](https://jsbin.com/sixerewiqe/edit?html,js,output)

```
describe("outer Describe", function(){
    var testArray;
    beforeEach(function(){
      testArray = [];
    });
    describe("First Describe", function(){
      beforeEach(function(){
        testArray.push({name: "foo"});
      });

      it("has an item", function(){
        expect(testArray.length).toBe(1);//passing
      });
    });

    describe("Second describe", function(){
      var arrIsEmptyInBeforeAll;
      var arrIsEmptyInBeforeEach;
      beforeAll(function(){
        arrIsEmptyInBeforeAll = testArray.length === 0;
        console.log("testArray should be empty:");
        console.log(testArray);//logs array with one item
      });

      beforeEach(function(){
        arrIsEmptyInBeforeEach = testArray.length === 0;
      });

      it("the arr was empty in before all", function(){
        expect(arrIsEmptyInBeforeAll).toBeTruthy(); //This is failing
      });

      it("the arr was empty in beforeEach", function(){
        expect(arrIsEmptyInBeforeEach).toBeTruthy();//Passing
      })
    })
  });
```

I would expect that the `beforeAll` inside the "Second Describe" would have an empty `testArray`, because the "outer Describe" has a `beforeEach` that initializes it as an empty array. However, in the `beforeAll` of "Second Describe", the `testArray` has the one item added in "First Describe"'s `beforeEach`.

Does this make sense? If so, could someone explain how beforeAll is supposed to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: You've a typo in your code ;) .. but that's not the problem.

```
expect(arrIsEmptyInBeforeAll).toBeTruthy();
```

**short answer**

*beforeAll* is always called before *beforeEach* in Jasmine, even if there are outer *beforeEach* statements.

**Your test is executed the following way:**

(Iteration of outer tests)

1. Outer beforeEach is called -> array is empty
2. "First Describe" beforeEach is called -> array becomes length = 1

(Iteration of inner tests)

1. "Second describe" beforeAll is called -> arrIsEmptyInBeforeAll is false because array is still set with one item
2. Outer beforeEach is called -> array is empty
3. "Second describe" beforeEach is called -> arrIsEmptyInBeforeEach is true because array was cleared
4. arrIsEmptyInBeforeAll is false in your test

Comment: Ok, I feel this wasn't explicitly stated in the documentation... I feel it's a bit weird that the outer describe beforeEach is run after the inner beforeAll. But this execution order explains my issue. Thanks